# How to hide html5 video custom controls when the mouse is not on hover and to leave only the progress control bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, video

I'am working on custom video player html5 video element. I want to add some interactivity to the custom controls. I want to hide all of the controls except the "time progress control bar" when the mouse is not on the video player, and want to show all the controls when mouse it's on the video player.

```
<div id="video_player_box">
    <video id="video">
        <source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="video/video.ogg" type="video/ogg">
        <track>
    </video>
    <!-- Button Bar -->      
    <div id="video_controls_bar">
        <input id="seekSlider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="1">
        <button id="playPauseBtn">Play</button>
        <span id="currentTimeText"></span> / <span id="durationTimeText"></span>
        <button id="muteBtn">Mute</button>
        <input id="volumeSlider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100" step="1">
        <button id="fullScreenBtn">[ &nbsp; ]</button>
    </div>


$('#video_player_box').hover(function() {
$("#video_controls_bar").slideDown("fast");

},function() {
$("#video_controls_bar").slideUp("slow");
});
```

But with code above I just slideUp and slideDown everything tryed different things but couldn't manage to leave only the progress bar when the mouse is not over the video. I'd be very thankful if you guys can give me a hand for this task thanks!

Comment: it's sliding all your controls down because you're telling it to slide down video_controls_bar. You need to explicitly say which id's  or move the progress outside of video_controls_bar

Comment: Ronnie ! Thank you I tryed to exclude only the element which i want to show from that slideUp/Down function but didn't happen. How could I miss this thanks ! I did it !